# Newbie Error deploying OLAP cube: attribute key duplicated

Tags: ssas, olap, cube

I have a simple dimension BP (Business Partner)

The primary key is t_bpid and is "mapped" to the t_BPid attribute.

I have added the Ccty (indicates the City) attribute without problems, dragging it from the Data Source View pane to the Attributes pane.

Then I want to add the description on the BP, so I drag the t_Name from Data Source View to the attributes.

BUT when I try to deploy I get the error:
"Duplicate Attribute Key"

What's the problem?
What's the difference with the t_Ccty attribute?

The t_Name attribute has

- KeyColumns set to BP.t_nama (WChar)
- NameColumn (none)

(PS. If I change KeyColumns to point to the BP primary key (BP.t_bpid) the error goes away but I don't think this is the correct way to address the problem...)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems your dim table in db have that records which one t_bpid mapped to multiple t_nama.

Try this :

select * from(
select t_nama,t_bpid,rownumber()over(partition by t_bpid order by t_nama) as rn 
from(
select distinct t_nama,t_bpid from yourtb) a
) b where rn>1

this query will return you the dim records that one t_bpid mapped to multiple t_nama.

If the query return records, then please make sure the key attribute in the dim is mapped to the primary key in db table also.

MDXHelper : IDE to Write, Analyze, Tuning, Debug MDX efficiently